# Select into random records using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my MySql database:

Employee Table:

```
   id   |   name   |   projectcount   
---------------------------------
     5    |   john    |     1
     7    |   mike    |     1
     8    |   jane    |     0
```

Project Table:

```
     id   |   name   |   employeeId   
---------------------------------
     1    |   pro1    |     5
     2    |   pro2    |     7
     3    |   pro3    |     8
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeTable (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  projectcount int
  );
  
CREATE TABLE ProjectTable (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  employeeId INT
  );
  
INSERT INTO EmployeeTable (id, name, projectcount) VALUES
(5, "john", 1),
(7, "mike", 1),
(8, "jane", 0);

INSERT INTO ProjectTable (id, name, employeeId) VALUES
(1, "pro1", 5),
(2, "pro2", 7),
(3, "pro3", 8);
```

I would like to select 3 random records from the projects table and update the projectcount in employees table and return those records using select query.

My Approach using Stored Procedure:

```
DECLARE userId1 int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE userId2 int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE userId3 int DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE projectId1 int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE projectId2 int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE projectId3 int DEFAULT 0;

select id, employeeid into projectId1, userId1 from project order by RAND() LIMIT 1;
select id, employeeid into projectId2, userId2 from project order by RAND() LIMIT 1;
select id, employeeid into projectId3, userId3 from project order by RAND() LIMIT 1;

update employee set projectcount = projectcount + 1 where id = userId1;
update employee set projectcount = projectcount + 1 where id = userId2;
update employee set projectcount = projectcount + 1 where id = userId3;

select * from project where id in (projectId1, projectId2, projectId3);
```

The above code works but written in more static way. Is there any improvements done to this to look more cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: you risk having duplicates with that particular example.

Comment: @Mech: yes, you are correct.

Comment: 1) Final SELECT will return not 3 rows but from 1 to 3 rows depends on the amount of rows which were ncremented more than once. Is it correct (it seems - yes)? 2) Do you really need to update three rows, or in real situation it may be hundreds-thousands-more? Does iterational processing to solid single-query one makes sense?

Comment: @AKina: I will only select random 3 records. Yes, the final result may not return 3 records, I think this issue will be resolved when we cleanup the code.

Comment: You wouldn't generally store such easily derived data. And you definitely wouldn't bother with a sproc.

Comment: Won't that sometimes assign 2 or 3 projects to a single employeeid?  Perhaps you did not intend that, so we need to start over?

Answer (score 1):

**PLan A**

"Is there any improvements done to this to look more cleaner."  Do only one request at a time.

Since that probably does not satisfy your *intended* meaning of "cleaner", I will continue:

**Plan B**

Flip things around.  And use a transaction.

This runs 3 times as fast, and fixes one potential bug.  Does that qualify as "cleaner"?

```
BEGIN;

SELECT @ids := GROUP_CONCAT(id)
    -- I assume that `id` is the PRIMARY KEY of `project`?
    from project
    order by RAND() LIMIT 3;
-- That will run 3 times as fast as 3 separate SELECTs.
-- It avoids tallying the same id 3 times
-- but it may hit the same employee 3 times

SET @sql = CONCAT("UPDATE employee
      SET projectcount = projectcount + 1
      WHERE id IN (", @ids, ")");
PREPARE _sql FROM @sql;
EXECUTE _sql;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE _sql;

...  -- similar execute to get the `SELECT *`

COMMIT;
```

If you have millions of rows you are picking from, then be aware that `ORDER BY RAND()` always requires a full table scan and a sort.  Here are some kludges to speed that up:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

**Plan C**

Tighten up the specs (no dup projects, double-assigning a user, define "cleaner", etc) Then we can look for other ways.

Comment: I am getting the warning when creating the stored procedure: "Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release"